# Cannot force change Detection in Loading Bar Component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-changedetection

I'm having a tough time understanding why I cannot get a progress bar to show up correctly in my app. I have tried several things to force change detection, and to just see what is going on. Below is the scenario.

I am going through a list of Objects and formatting them, as I am going through each selected object in our system, I call the following:

```
this._dialog.loadingBarCurrentIndex.next(progress);
```

where progress is a whole number between 0 and 100.

The dialog service is pretty basic for this use, and contains the following (pertinent for this question)

```
public loadingBarCurrentIndex = new Subject<any>();
public _loadingBarCurrentIndex$ = this.loadingBarCurrentIndex.asObservable();
```

I subscribe to this observable in my "transition-loader" component like so:

```
currentIndexSub: Subscription;
...
constructor(
    private _dialog: DialogService
) {
    this.currentIndexSub = this._dialog._loadingBarCurrentIndex$.subscribe(res => {
        this.loadingBarCurrentIndex = res;
        console.log(this.loadingBarCurrentIndex); //Shows loading values in real time...
    });
}
```

So far so good. I can console log res here and see it changing from 0 to 100 over the course of however long the calling function is executing.

My question is, why can't I get this value to update in my template? I have tried the following:

1. Forcing the current index to run inside of `ngZone.run()`
2. Setting this.loadingBarCurrentIndex value inside of a `setTimeout` function to force change detection
3. actually putting something like `this.cd.detectChanges()` after I try and assign the new value as well.

None of these methods work, though I can see the value clearly changing in the console. Nevermind any question about the component, considering at this point all I have in there is:

```
<p>{{loadingBarCurrentIndex}}</p>
```

Any ideas on what I might do differently? Whatever I do seems to not make a difference.

Comment: can you please create a minimal reproduction example? Also, try to have `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`. Maybe your `.next()` method works before `.subscribe()`?

Comment: I can, it'll take me a while to get one ready. Using ```Subject``` vs ```Behavior Subject``` doesn't change anything.

Comment: The necessary component still gets the value, it just never is able to display properly on the loader itself.

Comment: hmm, strange, everything else seems to be good.

Comment: I know. This loader shows up in a mat-dialog... I don't think that throws anything off with the component getting the value it needs though...

Comment: One question: You are using the same instance of your service, right?

Comment: the .next() call is one instance of the service inside of another service, the subscribe is a subscription in my loader component

Comment: Can you please try to change the service observable value from the component, where you are going to show value of the observable, and see it will be changed or not

Answer (score 0):

If you need progressbar progress percentage in template then there is not need to subscribe all you need to return the `Observable` and use that in template by using `async` pipe, checkout the following.

```
 // Initialize current index as Observable 
 loadingBarCurrentIndex$: Observable<number>; 

 // Assign the current index response to Observable (do not subscribe)
 this.loadingBarCurrentIndex$ = this._dialog._loadingBarCurrentIndex$;
```

Now in template use `async` pipe to subscribe the current index Observable (async pipe will unsubscribe automatically so no need to unsubscribe manually).

```
<p>{{ loadingBarCurrentIndex$ | async }}</p>
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: It's getting used in an entirely different component, not the template for the component generating the value for the bar. I tried what you said as well, still not changing anything.

Comment: If you dispatching Subject by next in a separate service then you can offcourse can inject that service and read the Observable from any other component where you are using the progress bar it should work.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. The problem is, I can't actually force the template to get the correct value. I can console log just fine, but can't get the actual value needed in the template